# Why I cannot create a stream iterator?

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

I am supposed to create a looks-like stream iterator class so that I can read from the input stream when incrmenting an object of my class.

I've done this:

```
template<class T>
struct istrm_it{
    istrm_it() = default;
    istrm_it(std::istream& in) :
        in_(in), val_(T()) {
        in_ >> val_;
    }
    T val_;
    std::istream& in_ = std::cin;
    istrm_it& operator++() { in >> val_; return *this; };
    istrm_it& operator++(int) { in_ >> val_; return *this; };
    T operator*() { return val_; }
    bool operator==(const istrm_it& rhs)const { return in_ == rhs.in_; }
    bool operator!=(const istrm_it& rhs) const{ return in_ != rhs.in_; }
};

int main(){

    istrm_it<int> it(std::cin), e;
    cout << *it << endl; // ok

    it++; // ok read the next value from the nput stream

    vector<int> vi;
    while (it != e) // the problem here
        vi.push_back(*it++);

    for (auto i : vi)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

What I get: `Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '!=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the comparison `in_ != rhs.in_` (and `in_ == rhs.in_` as well). You can't compare *streams*.

Instead you need to keep some kind of "is end iterator" or "is at end-of-file" state that is set when you reach end-of-file, and which is set by default in the default-constructed iterator object.

Comment: Ok I get it. Could you show me how to solve it? I only want to do it for the educational purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As `@Some programmer dude`: Stream objects can neither be copied, assigned nor compared.

If you want to make it works for some educational purpose then you can add another member to your class `istrm_iter` that keeps track of the stream state it is bound to and in in/equality operators compare there iterators whether their internal state is good or not so if both of them are good then they are equal and this occur when they are `off-end` otherwise they are not equal:

The default constructor which doesn't bind the iterator to a stream should make the internal state bad.

And the `++` should check after each input operator whether the stream hits the `EOF` or had reported an IO error thus it sets the status to bad. which makes it equal to the one constructed with default constructor (as off-the-end iterator).

Here is a simple suggestion:

```
template<class T>
struct istrm_it {
    istrm_it() = default;
    istrm_it(std::istream& in) :
        in_(in), val_(T()),
        is_good_(true) {
        in_ >> val_;
    }
    bool is_good_ = false;
    T val_ = T{};
    std::istream& in_ = std::cin;
    istrm_it& operator++() { in_ >> val_; if (!in_) is_good_ = false; return *this; };
    istrm_it& operator++(int) { in_ >> val_;  if (!in_) is_good_ = false; return *this; };
    T operator*() { return val_; }
    bool operator==(const istrm_it& rhs) const {
        return is_good_ && rhs.is_good_ || !is_good_ && !rhs.is_good_;}
    bool operator!=(const istrm_it& rhs) const{ return !(operator==(rhs)); }
};
```

and in main:

```
int main(){
    istrm_it<int> it(std::cin), e;
    cout << *it << endl;

    vector<int> vi;

    while (it != e)
        vi.push_back(*it++);


    for (auto i : vi)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

No it works. N.B This is just an example I know in real it takes a lot of stuff to mimick the class defined by the standard library.